# Moodle on EFS is slow

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, moodle

I hope you can help me with me problem with EFS.

I have installed Moodle on an Amazon EC2 and I mounted EFS following the guides provided in the website.

The problem I face is that Moodle is very slow when using EFS.

I did the following tests:

1. EFS + RDS = slow
2. EFS + local MySQL = slow
3. Local Filesystem + RDS = perferct perfomance
4. Local Filesystem + Local MySQL= perferct perfomance

EFS performance is set to Max I/O and I have read the additional considerations here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-cmd-general.html

Is there anything else that I miss?

Could you please give me some ideas, on what might be the problem?

Thank you for your time to read this post

Comment: There are known issues with running PHP from NFS. Try using PHP 7 with  opcache on local disk - might help.

Comment: Even when using the max I/O setting for EFS, the amount of IOPS you get is still based on the size of the data stored in EFS. Check EFS in cloudwatch. If you see that your burst credits is low or 0, then you are bottlenecked on IOPS and need to increase the amount of data stored on the EFS volume.

Comment: Check [this](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/06/02/running-php-on-nfs-huge-performance-problems-and-one-simple-solution/).

Comment: You need to start using CloudWatch to work out what the problem is. Is it out of IO credits? Not enough bandwidth? Too much disk latency? You could try a RAM disk or an instance with an ephemeral store, depending what's in there. Unless someone has solved it before you'll have to resort to problem solving, and no-one but you has the information.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. One solution is to create a virtual server with network performance and SSD disks and makeit the NFS for the EC2 instances. Sounds insane, but EFS doesn´t work.

If you get the things done in AWS/EFS, please let me know how.

Comment: Yes we did it. What we found after a lot of testing was that the problem was the caching. So i created an ElasticCache node using memcached. I added the memcached to the Moodle cache stores and i changed the mappings of the application caches to work with elastic cache. Everything worked after that. So moodle core and moodledata on efs. Caching on elasticcache